# Running E2E-Tests in parallel

Tags: selenium, vaadin, browserstack, vaadin-testbench

we are trying to run Selenium-Tests on Browserstack against an AWS-Vaadin-App on several Jenkins slaves in parallel.

```
Companies-Jenkins -> Browserstack -> AWS-Vaadin-App
```

Our test framework uses the Vaadin Testbench with a valid license key.

All tests start as expected with a login (at the app) and the business workflow. But after a while there is a connection closed on all tests, the Vaadin framework shows "server connection lost".

```
T0 -> T1
   -> T2
   -> Tn
```

If we run the same on just one Jenkins slave in a sequence, it runs ok (also here we can see sometimes "server connection lost" but the selenium tests tries to wait and go on when the warning disappears, usually that works. In parallel it never works).

```
T0 -> T1 -> T2 -> Tn
```

Do you have an idea, why this happens? Could it be a problem with our Vaadin license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got help from the browserstack support:

> eg. Initiate a Binary connection as:
>
> ./BrowserStackLocal --key $BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY --local-identifier test123
> This initiates a unique Binary connection with a unique modifier "test123". This can then be used when executing the tests by setting the below capabilities:
>
> caps.setCapability("browserstack.local","true");
> caps.setCapability("browserstack.localIdentifier", "test123");
>
> The same details are also mentioned in the link: https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/app-automate#multiple-local-testing-connections

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a problem with the server, not the tests. Is your server running out of memory by doing too much in parallel? Check the server logs, that is where you should find the reason. You can most likely see the same "server connection lost" if you manually open a session in your browser while the tests are running

Comment: We checked that, it turned out that we needed to add an identifier at the browserstack remote driver.